# Programmatically clicking 'submit' button in UIWebView (no element id, name, class or tag)

Tags: javascript, html, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I have the following code that fills the username and password fields of a website login form loaded in my `UIWebView` with some credentials.

```
   NSString *usernamescript = @"document.getElementById('h_username').value='testingusername';";
    [self.scrape stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:usernamescript];
    NSString *passwordscript = @"document.getElementById('h_password').value='testingpassword';";
    [self.scrape stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:passwordscript];
```

These successfully fill the input fields as both the elements have an individual `id` that I can reference.

However, the submit button does not have an element, id, name, class or tag that I can utilise to send the click action to.

```
<span class="button"><input value="Log in" type="submit"/></span></div>
```

How can I send a click to this particular submit button with these means of identifying which button on the page I am trying to refer to?

This is the button in context of the form:

```
><div id="login"><div class="inner"><form id="homepageRegisteredLogin" action="/login/registeredUserUsernameAndPasswordLogin" method="post"><fieldset><legend class="off-screen">Login</legend><span class="label">Log in to my Opal account:</span><p id="loginErrorMessageBox" style="color: #fef7f5; background: #d21f01; text-align:center; margin: 0;display:none;"></p><div><label class="placeholder" for="h_username" id="username-label">Username</label><input maxlength="250" name="h_username" id="h_username" type="text"/>&nbsp;<label class="placeholder" for="h_password" id="password-label">Password</label><input maxlength="150" name="h_password" id="h_password" type="password"/>&nbsp;<input value="" name="attempt" type="hidden"/><span class="button"><input value="Log in" type="submit"/></span></div><a title="Forgot your username or password?" href="/login/forgotten">Forgot your username or password?</a></fieldset><div><input type="hidden" name="CSRFToken" value="28846d41-89b0-40ba-ae0f-6b644480385c"/>
```

Perhaps a useful information would be:   `form id="homepageRegisteredLogin"` ?

Comment: why don't you give `name` attribute to the `input`?

Comment: @fedorqui The website is not mine, I am using it to webscrape/sitescrape

Comment: Mmmm and what about `getElementByTagName`? http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbytagname.asp and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByTagName

Comment: @fedorqui Could you possibly provide an answer on how this could work?

Comment: Honestly, not really. If you provide a JSFiddle I can play around a little bit, but I am unable to write something from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

### EDITED after comments below

```js
document.querySelector("input[type=submit]").click();
```

```html
><div id="login"><div class="inner"><form id="homepageRegisteredLogin" action="/login/registeredUserUsernameAndPasswordLogin" method="post"><fieldset><legend class="off-screen">Login</legend><span class="label">Log in to my Opal account:</span><p id="loginErrorMessageBox" style="color: #fef7f5; background: #d21f01; text-align:center; margin: 0;display:none;"></p><div><label class="placeholder" for="h_username" id="username-label">Username</label><input maxlength="250" name="h_username" id="h_username" type="text"/>&nbsp;<label class="placeholder" for="h_password" id="password-label">Password</label><input maxlength="150" name="h_password" id="h_password" type="password"/>&nbsp;<input value="" name="attempt" type="hidden"/><span class="button"><input value="Log in" type="submit"/></span></div><a title="Forgot your username or password?" href="/login/forgotten">Forgot your username or password?</a></fieldset><div><input type="hidden" name="CSRFToken" value="28846d41-89b0-40ba-ae0f-6b644480385c"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the login form does not support this request method, 'GET', according to the HTTP 405 error code I received. Do you think there is any other alternate method I could possible use?

Comment: try the other way above, although it seems something else is wrong, neither of the ways I posted change the form method.

Comment: Still no luck with this method.

Comment: well they're clicking the submit button, so it's something else that's wrong.the first way is better as it's submitting the proper form where as this way is clicking any submit button so if there's more than one it is possible to click the wrong button.Go back to `document.getElementById('homepageRegisteredLogin').submit();` and find out what else is wrong. Somewhere along the line it's getting  changed to the GET method instead of POST.

Comment: The old answer is correct answer I figure - it is the website's end which encounters some issues (which can be fixed by some redirects)

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful to you . . .

```
 NSString *performSubmitJS = @"var passFields = document.querySelectorAll(\"input[type='submit']\"); \
        passFields[0].click()";
 [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:performSubmitJS];
```